# Material keyframes don't show up

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm working with a mesh materials, changing the *Fac* of a mix shader to play with different colours. However, when I keyframe the *Fac* no keyframe is added in the timeline.

The animation can be played without problem respecting my instructions, but there's nothing in the timeline once again. Yes, I'm selecting my object. When I click the *Jump to previous Keyframe* button, Blender tells me there's no keyframe

Comment: You need to select both the object and the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, animation editors show only the selected content's key ticks.

Either you disable this by unchecking the `Only selected` button in the header.

Or, you can select both the object wearing the material, and the node on which you have keys.